# Node.js Winston elastic search logger

Tags: node.js

In my node app I am using Winston-elastic search for logging to print errors and I am dumping this logs to elastic search.

But I need one more functionality that if my elastic search cluster is down I want to dump this logs to flat file.I just used this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-elasticsearch).

Here is the code which I have written:

```
var client =  new elasticsearch.Client({localhost:9200});
var logger = new winston.Logger({
  exceptionHandlers : [ new Elasticsearch({
    json : true,
    index : 'exception',
    client : client
  }) ],
 exitOnError : false
});
```

Comment: Can you add some code?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way from the documentation.

But if you want to do, you can do this way:

Check for logger error. 
If it is Elastic Search Logger error, add File Transport

```
logger.emitErrs = true;
logger.on('error', function (err) {
    // Check err contains msg for Elastic Search Log.
    // Add File Tansport.
    // Note* : Please check File Transport exist or not. If exists do not add second time
});
```

Comment: Yes we can use this method but issue is how can i get the log which is not dumped to elastic search.

Comment: Winston is streaming logs asynchronously, so i don't think it would be possible. There will be some drop of logs surely. On error, you can add another transport, so from there further logs will be recorded